# square checkout duplicating users

Tags: square-connect, square, square-checkout

I'm using square checkout to create a payment screen

```
$checkout = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreateCheckoutRequest();   
$checkoutUrl = $result->getCheckout()->getCheckoutPageUrl();
```

I successfully get the lineitems and taxes, names and prices etc.
We *pass* along the users email address and name to this endpoint which appear on the checkout screen successfully.

In my app users can create accounts which also create square customers, we store the customer ID in our data base.

When I make a payment I am redirected to a page on my website:

```
$checkout->setRedirectUrl("https://www.example.net/order-complete");
```

I receive the get variables successfully.

** Note: I have turned off Instant profiles!

The transaction creates a **NEW Customer**  duplicate in the square POS back end instead of tying the transaction to the email address we provided.

This creates a new user ID which means we can't link the items a user orders together because each order creates a new user.

Why is this?
How do I tie an order to a user????

Do I need to create the customer order pages and manually create the order using:

```
$api = createChargeRequest();
```

Thank you, this is driving me mad that you cannot get the checkout to tie the order to a customer. I have searched websites and documentation but can find nothing except instant profiles, which have been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Checkout API does not check for customer duplicates and will always create a new customer based on the information provided.

For more control over your customer creation, you should look into the [Square Payment Form](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/what-it-does) and [Transactions API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/overview), which would allow you to create your own credit card form, and attach a customer to the payment (ie if they already exist, you can look up their `customer_id` and pass it along the request).

Comment: Thanks, I'm so mad that I have to code that entire page, add address fields etc when square could just implement such a simple addition by allowing devs to add something which checks for an existing customer by email or ID. Thank you for your help

Comment: So having been at this 2 hours reading the documentation and looking all over the web for an answer, I cannot get the fieldsets to create iframes like the documentation says you can. No where is it clear if fieldsets have to go in subsets etc.

Here:
 https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/what-it-does

What I want to achieve but with address: (is there an example of the actual code for this image)
https://connectv2-docs-production-f.squarecdn.com/assets/docs/sqpaymentform/diagram-sqpaymentform-custom-f06e4b80d985fbf45473a032d610a9f426aeecb08b9375bbc7329e79a941a904.png

Comment: Take a look at our samples here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/sample-app (all the ones labeled as Payment Processing Samples are using the Payment form). The payment form is essentially just fields that our server-hosted javascript will look up and replace with iframes. You can integrate these fields into your own form (so you can include address, name fields, etc).

Comment: Why did you bother answering the question sjosey?

I made it clear that I had read the documentation. I need to add a shipping address and following the documentation (which is extremely poorly written and very unclear) I cannot get the address fields to show. Are you able to provide a working example or not?

Comment: We do not have an example that includes addresses. You can create a simple HTML form to do this, though. Ex:
`<form...>`

  `<div id="sq-card-number"></div>`

  // rest of payment fields

  // address fields:

  `<input type="text" name="address_line_1">`

  `<input type="text" name="address_line_2">`

  `<input type="text" name="city">`
  // etc...
`</form>`

Apologies for the terrible formatting, SO doesn't allow code blocks in comments.

Comment: I ended up writing my own form and error checking, not what I expected I was going to need to do. Thank you for your help.